# With BitBake, can I set permissions to 000?

Tags: linux, chmod, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

In a BitBake `.bbappend` file, I have the following:

```
SRC_URI += "file://foo.file"
do_install_append() {
  install -m 000 foo.file ${D}${sysconfdir}/foo.file
}
FILES_${PN} += "${sysconfdir}/foo.file"
```

The `foo.file` is created in the proper directory, but the permissions are `-rw-------`. Within a normal shell, I can `install -m 000` on a file which sets permissions to `----------` just fine.

Is there a way to remove read & write privileges for the file owner using BitBake?

**UPDATE**: I've run the following commands within an `IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND`:

```
install -m 0000 ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}/foo.file ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/root
ls -lah ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/root >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/root/lslog
```

After the `bitbake` has finished execution, I navigate to `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/root` and do an `ls -la` and I see that the permissions on `foo.file` are `-rw-------`, but when I look what's inside the  `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/home/root`, the permissions are `----------`.  I thought this might help diagnose what's going on here.

Comment: Note that you're not using `chmod` here. How does your `install` behave if you call it with `-m 000` directly from the shell? Mine behave as expected but `install`s vary.

Comment: Just tested `install -m 000` from a shell and it set permissions to `----------`

Comment: That's interesting. The issue might then actually be related to BitBake (maybe it defines its own `install` as a shell function?), which, unfortunately, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot up the image on your target machine and you'll find that the file permissions appear as they are in your `lslog`, the file permissions are changed *after* the image creation process is complete.